# Is the Midrash Chad Shenati available online?

Tags: history, jewish-books, midrash, archaeology, genizah-storage

According with [this article](http://thetorah.com/a-monogamous-isaac-prays-for-his-barren-wife/), Midrash Chad Shenati was discovered in the Cairo Genizah almost a century ago. It is an early medieval midrashic collection most likely of eastern provenance, dating from the late tenth/early eleventh century.

Does anybody know any additional information about this? Is there any discussion as to its validity or its use in other sources in ancient/modern times? It was already published? Is this Midrash available online somewhere?

Comment: `It was already published?` Are you asking whether it has been published? something else?

Comment: `Is there any discussion as to its validity` Most question regarding the validity of Midrashim focus on their date pf authorship; it looks like you have already dated it. | Medieval midrashic works of unknown authors, rarely have practical ramifications, so I am not sure what sort of "validity" you seek to investigate.

Comment: Interestingly, some google searches for the Midrash yield just that single page that you linked. Consider contacting the authors of the piece.

Comment: @mevaqesh, regarding your 1st question, exactly. The 2nd one, "its validity" in the sense of incorporating it on the rest of the known midrashim we have. But I'll follow your advice, I'll contact the authors for further information on this.

Comment: Please post their response, in order to share your newfound knowledge with others.

Comment: Much of these fragments, collectively known as known as מדרש חדש על התורה were published by Mann (mentioned in @Harel13‘s answer). The title ‘Midrash Chad Shenati’ I personally haven’t seen provided elsewhere other than in the linked-to article. Also, the central piece in that article I haven’t been able to locate its exact construct in Mann’s publication or in the later publication of this midrash (Zichron Aharon, Jerusalem 2018).

Answer (score 2):

All Genizah manuscripts are uploaded to the [Genizah](https://fjms.genizah.org) website (sign-up, for free, required) and can be viewed in the Cairo Genizah section. The portion of Midrash Chad Shenati quoted all over the internet is numbered **[CUL: T-S C2.42](https://fgp.genizah.org/FgpFrames.aspx?mainSiteType=false&lang=eng&UIT=ced7a140-be34-4012-a9e1-4d3dc7c240db)** - CUL referring to the Cambridge University Library collection, also known as the CUL Cambridge collection.

I asked the Genizah site about this midrash and I received the following list of manuscripts which they said are considered to be part of this midrashic anthology:

> Cambridge, CUL, T-S C1.45, T-S C2.42, T-S C2.178, T-S AS 62.61,
>
> London, BL, OR 10587.23,
>
> Manchester A1084, A 1087, A 1807

And they recommended further to check out the bibliographies of each manuscript.

I haven't gone through all of them yet, but as the three I've seen so far are titled מדרש על התורה, I assume they all are.

From what I've managed to gather, all relevant midrashim were published in the two volumes of [Jacob Mann's The Bible As Read And Preached In The Old Synagogue](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%A7%D7%91_%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%9F#The_Bible_as_Read_and_Preached_in_the_Old_Synagogue), which from what I understand is a book about the the annual and triennial Torah reading cycles; Mann based some of his theories on the discovery of what appear to be annual-based Midrashim, i.e., midrashim that open up with the first words of the parshas all communities follow nowadays. Unfortunately, these books are not available online. They can be bought used in some online stores and many libraries also have them, but obviously, due to corona-restraints, accessing those isn't quite so simple.

Edit: I've just discovered that the midrashim were republished separate from Mann's book, as מדרש חדש על התורה, which can be bought [here](https://www.schocken-jts.org.il/hebrew/bookstore/prodview.asp?idProduct=393), [here](https://www.schocken-jts.org.il/english/bookstore/prodView.asp?idproduct=393) or [here](https://seforimcenter.com/Midrash-Chadash-al-HaTorah-Zichron-Aharon-Edition__p-12309.aspx).

Example directions for navigating the Genizah site:

In the search engine, in choose library, choose the Cambridge CUL:

[image]

Next, in select collection, choose the T-S A-K:

[image]

Then, you may choose which set of manuscripts you want. For example, T-S C1:

[image]

Here you may select which portions of the set you want to view:

[image]

After selecting the texts you want, you can choose a command. For example, to view transcriptions, press Transcriptions. To view scans of the texts, press Images. And so forth.

[image]

Good luck!